# Sort PHP multidimensional array [Value1],[Value2]

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this Array:

```
[0] => Array
    (


        [tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => MusicVideos, #20
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (

        [tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => MusicVideos, #5
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (


        [tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => #9, MusicVideos
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (

        [tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => #12, MusicVideos
            )

    )
```

Now I would like to sort this array by [tags] How do I do this this PHP?
Using the Online tool [Tags] use to order in my website by i want "#1", "#2"

But i have one more than [Tags] Like "#1" and "Category"

`[Tags] => #1
[Tags] => MusicVideos, #2
[Tags] => #3`

is possible order like this ?

I try use this function:

```
function msort($array, $key, $sort_flags = SORT_NUMERIC) {
if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0) {
    if (!empty($key)) {
        $mapping = array();
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            $sort_key = '';
            if (!is_array($key)) {
                $sort_key = $v[$key];
            } else {
                // @TODO This should be fixed, now it will be sorted as string
                foreach ($key as $key_key) {
                    $sort_key .= $v[$key_key];
                }
                $sort_flags = SORT_STRING;
            }
            $mapping[$k] = $sort_key;
        }
        asort($mapping, $sort_flags);
        $sorted = array();
        foreach ($mapping as $k => $v) {
            $sorted[] = $array[$k];
        }
        return $sorted;
    }
}
return $array;
```

}

But this SORT by ALL introduce EMPTY after NAME and next NUMBER

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => #5
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => Commercials, #3
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => Commercials, #9
            )


    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => MusicVideos, #1
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => MusicVideos, #10
            )


    )
```

AND i want something like THIS:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => MusicVideos, #1
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => Commercials, #3
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => #5
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => Commercials, #9
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [tags] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => MusicVideos, #10
            )

    )
```

Thanks

Comment: Are the tags themselves (in the 'tags' field) already in sorted order?  I.e. Would I find 'tags' fields containing `MusicVideos, #5`? If so would `MusicVideos, #5` sort before `#12, MusicVideos`?

Comment: i Use VIMEO API and they sometimes sort sometimes not or change the order of Tags.
If possible i want search where is the array with ("#1", "#2") and order by that, is possible ?

Comment: You can use [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#example-4927), I dont understand by you want to sort

Comment: @EmilioGort Using the [TAGS] i want to order by that number :)

Comment: But `MusicVideos, #5` or `#12, MusicVideos` this have to be uniformed  to sort by number, in ASC order `#12, MusicVideos` is before to `MusicVideos, #5`, post the array like you are getting, in code format

Comment: Let me try to explain :)

When i go to edit the tags on VIMEO, he change the order of tags put the #NUMBER last "SOMETIMES".

What i need is to SORT my Multidimensional Array by TAGS, and this way i can choose who put first

Comment: It would be best to add that extra detail to your question, specifically, how sorting by TAGS is supposed to work, with some examples. As Emilio points out, normally `#12, MusicVideos` sorts before `MusicVideos, #5`, is this a problem? How do you select which individual tag to sort by, considering that in the general case #(number) tags may not even be present?

Comment: The ORDER if is MusicVideo, #5 or #5, MusicVideos, for me is indifferent. What i want is SORT all the ARRAY search all #NUMBER and order by that #1, #2, #3, #4 ... :))

Comment: For you is indifferent, not for php

Comment: @EmilioGort have change the order in VIMEO the NUMBER# and use the last Function, ORDER NUMBER FIRST and SORT BY NUMBER AND NOT BY #

Thanks for help guys :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with an appropriate callable to do the sorting.

The ordering function can use whatever logic to extract sorting fields. If you want to sort by the tag that starts with `#` followed by a number you'd need to find that substring in the tags field (here using a regex):

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    $matches = array();
    preg_match('/#(\d+)/', (string) $a['tags'], $matches);
    $aTagNo = (int) $matches[1];
    preg_match('/#(\d+)/', (string) $b['tags'], $matches);
    $bTagNo = (int) $matches[1];

    if ($aTagNo < $bTagNo)
        return -1;
    else if ($aTagNo > $bTagNo)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
});
```

Comment: HI !! And thanks to help but i try to use but show `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING`

I have update the Post maybe help you more to understand :s

Comment: Whoops, lots of missing semicolons, coding in Go will do that to you. Fixed, although I'm wondering how much you're familar with PHP if you could not fix that yourself.

Comment: I have update the question maybe this way do you can help me better :)
Thanks You so much for trying

Comment: This copypasting my code again and see if that does it, I think it does.

Comment: I have try to use you function but doesn't work for me.
but i have change the order #NUMBER to NUMBER# and put NUMBER FIRST and SORT with the function i have UP.

but I'm curious, trying to use your function

Comment: It may not work because of the SimpleXML structure, which is a little confusing, can you post your array as the source XML? (If you're calling a SOAP server, you may have to use `trace = true` and `SoapClient::__getLastResponse()` to retrieve this.